# Translating a Lambda Expression into Scheme

Tags: scheme, lambda-calculus

I have this lambda lambda expression : λx.(λy.(λz.x(yz)))

I'm trying to write a Scheme expression out of it.

I did this:

```
(define (f x)(lambda(y z) (f (y z))))
```

Is that right? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about that lambda notation but I think you need this:

```
(define (f x) (lambda (y) (lambda (z) (x (y z)))))
```

and you can use it like this:

```
(((f sqrt) 1+) 3)
2.0
```

Comment: Im using Win 7 and DrRacket:
I put (define (f x) (lambda (y) (lambda (z) (x (y z))))) in and press Enter and everything is ok.
But when i try to use it like you suggested i get: "reference to an identifier before its definition: 1+" Can you explain why?

Comment: @endif: `1+` is called `add1` in Racket.

Comment: There is no binding for 1+ in Racket. Try using add1.